# How to store multi data for each users in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have data which contain user and text with rating. I need to store it to database. I use MySQL as my database and using java, IDE netbeans. After storing these, I just read and insert new user with data.

```
User: a
Data: what are you doing, class: bad
      yes, this is me, class good
      how are you?, class bad

User: b
Data: what are you doing, class: good
      yes, this is me, class bad
      how are you?, class bad
```

How can I store these to MySQL (Xampp) or any other database could do this? Thank You

Comment: Even though you approved my answer as the approved answer, I felt an improvement to my answer was necessary. Please see below for an improvement to the normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about normalization. With proper normalization, you would have at least two tables, a user table and a data table. Your data table would then look like this:

```
user      |      data          |  rating
_________________________________________
a         | What are you doing | bad
a         | yes, this is me    | good
a         | how are you?       | bad
b         | what are you doing | good
b         | yes, this is me    | bad
b         | how are you?       | bad
```

Other things to optionally implement:

1. The data table could also have a unique (auto_increment) id used as a primary key
2. You could create a user table with other user info, such as first name, last name, etc. A primary key here (a, b) would link to a foreign key in the data table. I use a, b here as that is what you used, but you can also use an auto_increment field if they do not currently have a userid.

If all users have the same exact phrases (or many of the same phrases), then a better structure would be with three tables: A user table, a phrase table, and a rating table.

In this case the phrase table would look like this:

```
phrase_id |      phrase
________________________________
1         | What are you doing
2         | yes, this is me
3         | how are you?
```

and the rating table would contain a composite primary key of both user_id and phrase_id which would both be a foreign key reference to the user and phrase tables. That would make your rating table to look like this:

```
user_id | phrase_id |  rating
_________________________________________
a       | 1         | bad
a       | 2         | good
a       | 3         | bad
b       | 1         | good
b       | 2         | bad
b       | 3         | bad
```